# Duel WHERE clauses in MySql query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 2 Tables within my Database.

Navigation Table

```
| id |   menu   | parent_id |
-----------------------------
| 1  | Thailand |     0     |
| 2  | Bangkok  |     1     |
```

Tours Table

```
| id |   parent_id   | city_id | name  |
----------------------------------------
| 1  |      1        |    2    | Tour 1
| 2  |      1        |    2    | Tour 2
```

My query statement is

```
$sql = DB::getInstance()->query(
    'SELECT 
        tours.id, 
        tours.parent_id, 
        tours.city_id, 
        tours.name, 
        navigation.id, 
        navigation.menu, 
        navigation.parent_id
    FROM 
        tours, navigation 
    WHERE 
        tours.parent_id = navigation.id'
);
```

This returns the following

```
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [parent_id] => 0
                [city_id] => 2
                [name] => RIVER KWAI ADVENTURE
                [price] => 18170
                [menu] => thailand
            )
```

What i would like it to return is the following

```
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [parent_id] => 0
                [city_id] => 2
                [name] => RIVER KWAI ADVENTURE
                [price] => 18170
                [menu] => thailand
                [menu] => bangkok
            )
```

How can i do this within the query?? Is it a duel `WHERE` clause??

EDIT TO THIS

This is what i am wanting to return

```
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [parent_id] => 0
                [city_id] => bangkok
                [name] => RIVER KWAI ADVENTURE
                [price] => 18170
                [menu] => thailand
            )
```

There is NO `menu` in the `tours` table

Comment: every key name is unique, you cannot have 2 `menu`s.

Comment: Use GROUP_CONCATE(navigation.menu)

Comment: @RaviHirani that's the worst advice someone might give

Comment: @zerkms: Let me explain it in answer.

Comment: You better not. `GROUP_CONCAT` is the terrible solution for this question.

Comment: OKay i am not familiar with `GROUP_CONCATE()` but i understand the concept

Comment: @b2b589 you just need to select 2 columns and rename them with `AS`, please do not use `GROUP_CONCAT` it's a silly solution.

Comment: @zerkms: Yeah. agree with you. Sorry for my earliest advice. I have to see question in detail.

Comment: What is the better solution @zerkms

Comment: @b2b589 I have already explained it in the last comment. "you just need to select 2 columns and rename them with `AS`"

Comment: @zerkms Great, that works. Thanks very much :-)

Comment: Use the navigation table twice and join by parent ? If you need to follow a chain like this it needs to be recursive. If you only need the immediate parent then select A.menu, B.menu where B.parent_id = A.id  from Navigation Table A, Navigation Table B etc.

Comment: Is Tour `price` stored in database table? If yes, where is the part of the query that returns the tour `price`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a join?

```
SELECT t.id AS [tourId], t.parent_id AS [tourParent_id], t.city_id, t.name, n.id as [navId], n.menu, n.parent_id AS [navParent_id]
FROM Tours t
JOIN Navigation n ON n.id = t.parent_id
```

Comment: That sort of works but i want the `city_id` to return the `menu` title, so in this case `bangkok`

Answer (score 0):

query should be  alias name

```
SELECT 
    tours.id, 
    tours.parent_id, 
    tours.city_id, 
    tours.name, 
    navigation.id, 
    navigation.menu as nav_menu, 
    tours.menu as tours_menu,
    navigation.parent_id
FROM 
    tours, navigation 
WHERE 
    tours.parent_id = navigation.id
```

Comment: How would this work? There is no `tours.menu` if you look at the tables above